# OFBiz task 'build' not found in root project 'ofbiz-release15.12'

Tags: gradle, gradlew, ofbiz

```
    > ➜  ofbiz-release15.12 ./gradlew build --debug

07:49:47.388 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Starting Build
07:49:47.411 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: /Users/qk/.gradle
07:49:47.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Current dir: /Users/qk/Documents/workspace-neon/ofbiz-release15.12
07:49:47.418 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings file: null
07:49:47.422 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Build file: null
07:49:47.477 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Starting to build the build sources.
07:49:47.481 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Gradle source dir does not exist. We leave.
07:49:47.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
07:49:47.498 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
07:49:47.736 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.mvnsettings.DefaultLocalMavenRepositoryLocator] No local repository in Settings file defined. Using default path: /Users/qk/.m2/repository
07:49:48.088 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on buildscript class cache for settings file '/Users/qk/Documents/workspace-neon/ofbiz-release15.12/settings.gradle' (/Users/qk/.gradle/caches/2.0/scripts/settings_74ne66nuu6asrd265d84ulhlp3/SettingsScript/buildscript).
07:49:48.092 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
07:49:48.175 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on no_buildscript class cache for settings file '/Users/qk/Documents/workspace-neon/ofbiz-release15.12/settings.gradle' (/Users/qk/.gradle/caches/2.0/scripts/settings_74ne66nuu6asrd265d84ulhlp3/SettingsScript/no_buildscript).
07:49:48.177 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
07:49:48.345 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor] Timing: Processing settings took: 0.843 secs
07:49:48.349 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings evaluated using settings file '/Users/qk/Documents/workspace-neon/ofbiz-release15.12/settings.gradle'.
07:49:48.473 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: /Users/qk/Documents/workspace-neon/ofbiz-release15.12/gradle.properties
07:49:48.475 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!
07:49:48.478 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: /Users/qk/Documents/workspace-neon/ofbiz-release15.12/framework/start/build/gradle.properties
07:49:48.480 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!
07:49:48.484 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Projects loaded. Root project using empty build file.
07:49:48.487 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Included projects: [root project 'ofbiz-parent', project ':ofbiz-start']
07:49:49.344 [INFO] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Evaluating root project 'ofbiz-parent' using empty build file.
07:49:49.385 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 0.038 secs
07:49:49.433 [INFO] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Evaluating project ':ofbiz-start' using empty build file.
07:49:49.452 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 0.017 secs
07:49:49.456 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] All projects evaluated.
07:49:49.501 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
07:49:49.504 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
07:49:49.507 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
07:49:49.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
07:49:49.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Task 'build' not found in root project 'ofbiz-parent'.
07:49:49.515 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
07:49:49.530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
07:49:49.532 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
07:49:49.535 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
07:49:49.539 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
07:49:49.546 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
07:49:49.549 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 3.664 secs
```

It is my first time using gradle and in ofbiz-release15.12 use gradlew to start the demo. It seems that all the tasks do not exist. I have /gradlew init build successful. How can I add the build task?

Comment: OFBiz release branch 15.12 does not contain Gradle, it was introduced in the current trunk only. Are you sure you have setup everything right?

Answer (score 0):

In OFBiz, Gradle has replaced Ant after the creation of the 15.12 branch.
In 15.12 you still have to use ant to build the system.
You can run:

```
./ant build
```

or you can get the list of tasks with:

```
./ant -p
```